# Get Email Address from MSG file using poi-scratchpad MAPIMessage

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read around 1000 msg file via Apache poi-scratchpad:4.1.2.

Following is the code extract:

```
    MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage("Dummy.msg");

    Chunks mainChunks = msg.getMainChunks();
    StringChunk emailFromChunk = mainChunks.getEmailFromChunk();
    String emailFrom = emailFromChunk.getValue();

    System.out.println("From: " + msg.getDisplayFrom());
    System.out.println("To: " + msg.getDisplayTo());
    System.out.println("CC: " + msg.getDisplayCC());
    System.out.println("BCC: " + msg.getDisplayBCC());
    System.out.println("Subject: " + msg.getSubject());
```

Now the problem is I am not able to fetch the "To" Email Address and "CC" Email Address. It gives blank.

I tried using an online service https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/ and it fetched all the information including emails.

While debugging i could see that there was a long String something like this:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=BLAH BLAH GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=C8B646DEEE4D4C8AAABC8324AC8A20A7-GOSSELIN, N
```

Is there somehow i could decode this? or Is there some other way to reetrieve the email id's.

Looking forward for some solution!